# Starting SWT widget from HttpServlet

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, swt

For some weird reason I need to open swt dialog from a servlet. Is this even possible?
Currently I have this but getting "Invalid thread access error". So far I am doing this.

```
        Thread th=new Thread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Shell shell = new Shell();
            FileDialog dialog=new FileDialog(shell);
            dialog.setText("Enter a filename");
            dialog.setFilterPath("c:\\");
            String selected=dialog.open();
            log.error(selected);
            shell.dispose();

        }

    });
    th.start();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I have a special use case, I just want to know if this is technically possible.

Comment: Could you explain your use case?

Comment: Sorry I cannot discuss my use case here. I just want to know if it is technically possible to create swt widget from a servlet within a local environment.

Comment: Swing seems to work fine so it might be possible to get SWT working.

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: To all who helped in putting this **question on hold** :Just I would like to know **What is unclear about the question being asked here?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't want to know the weird reason, at the same time I can't warn you about the problems you may run into while opening a `SWT` window in a `Servlet` but the problem is you are accessing `SWT` widgets from a Native `Thread` which won't work.

> You can access `SWT` only on `UI Thread`.

Also you are not blocking the `UI Thread`.

PFB the code which solves your problem

```
Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            Display.getDefault().syncExec(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    Display display = Display.getDefault();
                    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
                    FileDialog dialog=new FileDialog(shell);
                    dialog.setText("Enter a filename");
                    dialog.setFilterPath("c:\\");
                    String selected=dialog.open();
                    log.error(selected);
                    while (!shell.isDisposed())
                    {
                        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                            display.sleep();
                    }

                }

            });
        }
    });

    th.start();
```

Comment: Thanks I think this might work. I forgot to create new display.